# Editable JavaFX TableView with Objects

Tags: java, user-interface, object, javafx, tableview

I'm trying to crete an editable TableView in JavaFX. I'm getting data from 2 joined tables, so I use objects in the Tableview.

```
private TableColumn<Student, Classroom>classroomNameColumn, classroomYearColumn;
```

I have set the table and columns to be editable, `setEditable(true)`, I tried to do `setGraphic(node)` (for example like a textfield) on `setOnEditCommit` action of the column.

I have not been able to resolve this issue.

So, how can I make a cell which contains an object editable? Thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my solution was to create a custom `class` which inherits from `TableCell` and overrides the method for editing.